# Owning something temporarily

Tags: stative-verbs

If something is coming into my possession temporarily, and then I would like/have to relinquish ownership of it for whatever reason, is it then grammatical to say: "I'm owning it for two months only"?

Notes:

1. I understand there could be better ways to express this.
2. I understand there are other dynamics meanings for 'own'.

Answer (score 2):

Syntactically, you’re fine.  If you were doing anything else for a period of time, during that interval you could say, “I’m x-ing it.”  “I’m eating it.”  “I’m wearing it.”

Semantically, the word *own* doesn’t really describe temporary possession like that.  Ownership is notionally permanent, and if you are planning to relinquish the property, then you are borrowing it or leasing it or something.

Comment: So according to you it's impossible to plan to own something temporarily.

Comment: I don’t know about “impossible”.  Perhaps, “contrary to common usage”.  Most things you own you actually own temporarily, but if the end of your ownership is only a few months out, most English speakers would describe the situation with a different word.

Comment: It's not common usage to call owning leasing or borrowing! If you buy something and sell it it'l called owning. There's no semantic issue with the sentence. Cheers.

Comment: @BazAU - if I really wanted to still use "own," I'd probably want to emphasize the temporariness, since that is contrary to the general meaning of "ownership."  So I'd say something like, "I have temporary ownership for only two months."

Comment: @BazAU The sentence is grammatical, but my assumption is that you would have meant "I have owned it for two months (so far)" (since it's a reasonably common mistake for a lot of English-as-second-language speakers to use "I am Xing" where a native speaker wouldn't). I would probably say "I will sell it after two months" or "I will only keep it for two months".

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence is grammatical.

To *plan* to own something for two months, or any short period of time, creates a situation where *owning* may not the best description of the situation.  To call such a situation *owning* may be technically correct but it likely omits a more descriptive relationship.

If you *plan* to sell something after a short period, saying you *own* it doesn't tell me anything about your plan.